# does Azure ad v2Endpoint support API access other than the Microsoft Graph?

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory

I cloned the node web api from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-javascript-nodejs-webapi-v2/

An app was  registered in the v2 app registration portal, with a webapi platform added and a web app with implicit flow set

When i browse to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=5bab650d-e96c-4f30-a7e2-e6bbab2e7ab1&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000/hello&response_mode=query&scope=api%3A%2F%2F5bab650d-e96c-4f30-a7e2-e6bbab2e7ab1%2Faccess_as_user%20openid%20offline_access

the browser is redirected to

localhost:5000/hello?error=invalid_client&error_description=AADSTS65005%3a+The+application+%27hand2%27+asked+for+scope+%27openid%27+that+doesn%27t+exist+on+the+resource.+Contact+the+app+vendor.%0d%0aTrace+ID%3a+4b3bdc12-9c1c-448b-abbb-704e9af80d00%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+27afcaf6-cdac-428a-8c6b-7087ff8b34ef%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2017-10-11+00%3a41%3a40Z

Any idea ?

Comment: What is the resource you are trying to access from your app? 
The v2 endpoint currently supports access to the services and APIs listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations#restrictions-on-services-and-apis). We are working on adding support for accessing other APIs.